# How to get cover photo from a document created in a Facebook group?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using the graph API explorer trying to find the photo added as the cover photo of a created document in a facebook group.
I am using the api call `graph/v2.8/{group-id}/docs` to get all the documents, and that works. However, there are no fields from a single doc stating anything about a cover picture. when I get all the documents I get data such as:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "can_delete": true,
      "can_edit": true,
      "created_time": "2017-01-22T12:13:39+0000",
      "from": {
        "name": "name",
        "id": "someId"
      },
      "icon": "https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/y7/r/8zhNI-VGpiI.png",
      "message": "some HTML-formatted message",
      "revision": "revNr",
      "subject": "subject",
      "updated_time": "2017-01-23T10:08:46+0000",
      "id": "someDocId"
    }
  ]
}
```

Maybe it is possible to use the documentId in order to get the cover photo, but I don't seem to find the correct API call. Are there any special permissions I need to have as well? I am only using the `user_managed_groups` permission.

Comment: there does not seem to be any field for it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/groupdoc

Comment: That is too bad. Facebook are able to display the cover photo in the group, so thought they would have an API for it. I also tried to add images inside the document, but I am not able to get that image neither.